# The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Video>'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to get all videos uploaded on youtube to show up as a list but the problem is, it shows an error

```
"The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Video>'.
```

On

```
List<Video> allVideos = [];
allVideos =_channel.videos.addAll(moreVideos);
```

Load function

```
_loadMoreVideos() async {
        _isLoading = true;
        List moreVideos = await APIService.instance
            .fetchVideosFromPlaylist(playlistId: _channel.uploadPlaylistId);
        List<Video> allVideos = [];
        allVideos =_channel.videos.addAll(moreVideos);
        setState(() {
          _channel.videos = allVideos;
        });
        _isLoading = false;
      }
```

Comment: how about changing `List moreVideos` to `List<Video> moreVideos`?

Answer (score 0):

add it in your Model and use like `List`

example:

```
class VideoList {
  final List<Video>? video;

  VideoList({
    this.video,
  });

  factory VideoList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
    var video = <Video>[];
    video = parsedJson.map((i) => Video.fromMap(i)).toList();

    return VideoList(video: video);
  }
}
```

also change your response method like this

```
  Future<List<Video>?> getVideo() async {
    try {
      your response....

      final result = VideoList.fromJson(response.data!).video;

      return result;
    } catch (e) {
      ...
    }
  }
```